Why Talos shutdown after setup?
I have setup a Proxmox cluster on which I try deploy a Talos cluster (one controlplane, one worker) using Terraform.
I generate client and machine configurations, apply the machine conf, bootstrap the controlplane and apply the kubeconfig.
I see pods being created with warnings/errors and after a moment: "machine is running and ready". Right after, the VM shutdown for whatever reason, and without a trace on dmsg.
Anyone got the same issue?
Version:

Talos provider: 0.7.0-alpha0
Talos: v1.8.3
Proxmox: 8.3.0
Diskimage: from Factory (v1.8.3, nocloud, amd64 with extension "qemu-guest-agent")

Terraform:
# var.nodes is a list of nodes config used for VM creation and talos/machine config.
# I replaced it with values when possible.

resource "talos_machine_secrets" "this" {
  talos_version = "v1.8.3"
}

data "talos_client_configuration" "this" {
  cluster_name         = "homelab"
  client_configuration = talos_machine_secrets.this.client_configuration
  nodes                = ["10.0.1.101", "10.0.1.110"]
  endpoints            = ["10.0.1.101"]
}

data "talos_machine_configuration" "this" {
  for_each         = var.nodes

  cluster_name     = "homelab"
  cluster_endpoint = "https://10.0.1.101:6443"
  talos_version    = "v1.8.3"
  machine_type     = each.value.machine_type
  machine_secrets  = talos_machine_secrets.this.machine_secrets
}

resource "talos_machine_configuration_apply" "this" {
  depends_on = [proxmox_virtual_environment_vm.this]
  for_each                    = var.nodes
  node                        = each.value.ip
  client_configuration        = talos_machine_secrets.this.client_configuration
  machine_configuration_input = data.talos_machine_configuration.this[each.key].machine_configuration
  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [proxmox_virtual_environment_vm.this[each.key]]
  }
}

resource "talos_machine_bootstrap" "this" {
  depends_on = [ talos_machine_configuration_apply.this ]
  node                 = data.talos_client_configuration.this.endpoints[0]
  client_configuration = talos_machine_secrets.this.client_configuration
}

resource "talos_cluster_kubeconfig" "this" {
  depends_on = [talos_machine_bootstrap.this]
  node                 = data.talos_client_configuration.this.endpoints[0]
  endpoint             = data.talos_client_configuration.this.endpoints[0]
  client_configuration = talos_machine_secrets.this.client_configuration
}

Dmsg on control node:
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:17:16.05661311Z]: [talos] boot sequence: done: 45.924966917s
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:17:25.14749511Z]: [talos] controller failed {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.NodeApplyController", "error": "1 error(s) occurred:\n\ttimeout"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:17:37.62706111Z]: [talos] controller failed {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.NodeApplyController", "error": "1 error(s) occurred:\n\ttimeout"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:17:51.13721211Z]: [talos] controller failed {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.NodeApplyController", "error": "1 error(s) occurred:\n\ttimeout"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:04.64815911Z]: [talos] controller failed {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController", "error": "error creating mapping for object /v1/Secret/bootstrap-token-cnrdjh: Get \"https://127.0.0.1:7445/api?timeout=32s\": EOF"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:09.02385911Z]: [talos] controller failed {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.NodeApplyController", "error": "1 error(s) occurred:\n\ttimeout"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:10.24548811Z]: [talos] created /v1/Secret/bootstrap-token-cnrdjh {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:10.39570211Z]: [talos] created rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/ClusterRoleBinding/system-bootstrap-approve-node-client-csr {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:10.60099111Z]: [talos] created rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/ClusterRoleBinding/system-bootstrap-node-bootstrapper {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:10.62848911Z]: [talos] created rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/ClusterRoleBinding/system-bootstrap-node-renewal {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:10.64249111Z]: [talos] created rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/ClusterRole/flannel {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:10.65451411Z]: [talos] created rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/ClusterRoleBinding/flannel {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:11.02300011Z]: [talos] created /v1/ServiceAccount/flannel {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:11.39840711Z]: [talos] created /v1/ConfigMap/kube-flannel-cfg {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:11.85745211Z]: [talos] created apps/v1/DaemonSet/kube-flannel {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:12.21840711Z]: [talos] created apps/v1/DaemonSet/kube-proxy {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:12.61818211Z]: [talos] created /v1/ServiceAccount/kube-proxy {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:13.01240011Z]: [talos] created rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/ClusterRoleBinding/kube-proxy {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:13.42896611Z]: [talos] created /v1/ServiceAccount/coredns {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:13.84616711Z]: [talos] created rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/ClusterRoleBinding/system:coredns {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:14.22217511Z]: [talos] created rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/ClusterRole/system:coredns {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:14.60888111Z]: [talos] created /v1/ConfigMap/coredns {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:15.07381811Z]: [talos] created apps/v1/Deployment/coredns {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:15.52911911Z]: [talos] created /v1/Service/kube-dns {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:15.80581611Z]: [talos] created /v1/ConfigMap/kubeconfig-in-cluster {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.ManifestApplyController"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:17.70763811Z]: [talos] controller failed {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.NodeApplyController", "error": "1 error(s) occurred:\n\terror getting node: nodes \"controler-01\" not found"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:28.50990011Z]: [talos] controller failed {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.KubeletStaticPodController", "error": "error refreshing pod status: error fetching pod status: an error on the server (\"Authorization error (user=apiserver-kubelet-client, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)\") has prevented the request from succeeding"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:18:31.05698211Z]: [talos] controller failed {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "k8s.NodeApplyController", "error": "1 error(s) occurred:\n\terror getting node: nodes \"controler-01\" not found"}
10.0.1.101: user: warning: [2024-12-01T18:19:09.13014311Z]: [talos] machine is running and ready {"component": "controller-runtime", "controller": "runtime.MachineStatusController"}
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:22.00414011Z]: cni0: port 1(vethc443d987) entered blocking state
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:22.01698311Z]: cni0: port 1(vethc443d987) entered disabled state
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:22.02520211Z]: vethc443d987: entered allmulticast mode
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:22.03688411Z]: vethc443d987: entered promiscuous mode
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:22.11815111Z]: cni0: port 1(vethc443d987) entered blocking state
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:22.12966911Z]: cni0: port 1(vethc443d987) entered forwarding state
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:23.54569011Z]: cni0: port 2(veth2efaa20f) entered blocking state
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:23.54571311Z]: cni0: port 2(veth2efaa20f) entered disabled state
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:23.54573011Z]: veth2efaa20f: entered allmulticast mode
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:23.54582511Z]: veth2efaa20f: entered promiscuous mode
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:23.54589511Z]: cni0: port 2(veth2efaa20f) entered blocking state
10.0.1.101: kern:    info: [2024-12-01T18:19:23.54589611Z]: cni0: port 2(veth2efaa20f) entered forwarding state

Controller config:
version: v1alpha1
debug: false
persist: true
machine:
    type: controlplane
    token: yzcrjn.3ncoikcrdol6nhqn
    ca:
        crt: 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
        key: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBFRDI1NTE5IFBSSVZBVEUgS0VZLS0tLS0KTUM0Q0FRQXdCUVlESzJWd0JDSUVJSlB1R0puZmNJTTJjbVVtOVdadFRudUk4TkdvaW5BaGErRHdCaFNlMmErUQotLS0tLUVORCBFRDI1NTE5IFBSSVZBVEUgS0VZLS0tLS0K
    certSANs: []
    kubelet:
        image: ghcr.io/siderolabs/kubelet:v1.31.1
        defaultRuntimeSeccompProfileEnabled: true
        disableManifestsDirectory: true
    network: {}
    install:
        disk: /dev/sda
        image: ghcr.io/siderolabs/installer:v1.9.0-alpha.0
        wipe: false
    features:
        rbac: true
        stableHostname: true
        apidCheckExtKeyUsage: true
        diskQuotaSupport: true
        kubePrism:
            enabled: true
            port: 7445
        hostDNS:
            enabled: true
            forwardKubeDNSToHost: true
    nodeLabels:
        node.kubernetes.io/exclude-from-external-load-balancers: ""
cluster:
    id: bbNeeJ5ih8rcxrnVBIJeARbRq--ZVoSv0X3GYqrvuQY=
    secret: b8neVYsNEDaq/DlMoJiB3291LPOrmxra2SFibLglUvg=
    controlPlane:
        endpoint: https://10.0.1.101:6443
    clusterName: homelab
    network:
        dnsDomain: cluster.local
        podSubnets:
            - 10.244.0.0/16
        serviceSubnets:
            - 10.96.0.0/12
    token: n8zjw3.7vmywofpuzl1ii4r
    secretboxEncryptionSecret: 1xc3cMQ2yg3Ejf0Hg2Ksdskr6VrmxMHIq3I9NgZZYSs=
    ca:
        crt: 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
        key: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBFQyBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCk1IY0NBUUVFSUZHZnZNdlgrelBRYm9Tb2VhUnoyT3l3RFpvWngxRUxuREhiUFlsVjhHVUtvQW9HQ0NxR1NNNDkKQXdFSG9VUURRZ0FFRTVmc1UvZGZDT25hWnNyS1gyb211cW4raVNTdkg2M0Y0WEVYVjZYc2EzQ1FWRUdRRXJJRgpOcW1DcUNSc3hHbzBkWjl4a0E5cm96djI0TWJxcmN4L3lBPT0KLS0tLS1FTkQgRUMgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQo=
    aggregatorCA:
        crt: 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
        key: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBFQyBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCk1IY0NBUUVFSUtkaGFZb1U0akc2NmhuTi80OHFadWVleG1XcUVhaXZCU3JxNHp1NXQ4THBvQW9HQ0NxR1NNNDkKQXdFSG9VUURRZ0FFZ28zNE5tVFdwTlBWZnMxZTFMN2cvdFZVeXlUbjYxSDdiclducFA1Vk1TUml5M1JMZEFYSAp6YU1MV08yL1pnSnd3SEZaMUc2a0h6SjlvYWNrM2wzSVdBPT0KLS0tLS1FTkQgRUMgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQo=
    serviceAccount:
        key: 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
    apiServer:
        image: registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.31.1
        certSANs:
            - 10.0.1.101
        disablePodSecurityPolicy: true
        admissionControl:
            - name: PodSecurity
              configuration:
                apiVersion: pod-security.admission.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
                defaults:
                    audit: restricted
                    audit-version: latest
                    enforce: baseline
                    enforce-version: latest
                    warn: restricted
                    warn-version: latest
                exemptions:
                    namespaces:
                        - kube-system
                    runtimeClasses: []
                    usernames: []
                kind: PodSecurityConfiguration
        auditPolicy:
            apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1
            kind: Policy
            rules:
                - level: Metadata
    controllerManager:
        image: registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.31.1
    proxy:
        image: registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.31.1
    scheduler:
        image: registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.31.1
    discovery:
        enabled: true
        registries:
            kubernetes:
                disabled: true
            service: {}
    etcd:
        ca:
            crt: 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
            key: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBFQyBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCk1IY0NBUUVFSUxxY0NFVUw5clU0R0NmZEM2RG55L2xZVGJVNEFvS05jZWRvNzV3VnM2MS9vQW9HQ0NxR1NNNDkKQXdFSG9VUURRZ0FFL3lPOUI0a0hIVEFEN1ozUUcvZ1VuQnUybkhNR3gwUFZJNmRIeHRyb3RWdzZFUW53b3ZvQgpkT045WXA4UjhSMWRYbXA5QWkya2dPdzhxeFJ0OUtxellRPT0KLS0tLS1FTkQgRUMgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQo=

Worker config:
version: v1alpha1
debug: false
persist: true
machine:
    type: worker
    token: yzcrjn.3ncoikcrdol6nhqn
    ca:
        crt: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSUJQekNCOHFBREFnRUNBaEVBL3FRSTc2N2tXc2RsSVRCbmRDSzN5VEFGQmdNclpYQXdFREVPTUF3R0ExVUUKQ2hNRmRHRnNiM013SGhjTk1qUXhNakF4TVRjMU16QXhXaGNOTXpReE1USTVNVGMxTXpBeFdqQVFNUTR3REFZRApWUVFLRXdWMFlXeHZjekFxTUFVR0F5dGxjQU1oQUdpSTVBcHNST0RJZkVualVUQksxb0dGOVFYT2xOejVKVkVBClp4QVJIL0prbzJFd1h6QU9CZ05WSFE4QkFmOEVCQU1DQW9Rd0hRWURWUjBsQkJZd0ZBWUlLd1lCQlFVSEF3RUcKQ0NzR0FRVUZCd01DTUE4R0ExVWRFd0VCL3dRRk1BTUJBZjh3SFFZRFZSME9CQllFRkRpYStJS1lkQzBOK3FSVQpWSW9OOTA0WVF5NldNQVVHQXl0bGNBTkJBUG1tRzVzd09OM0lWbmlnOFh0cTl3QXVmNVlaSXB0NytOYWNOMnJtClVjaWdReENKNjBhdG82UGp5NGdnWkFsaTZHa1QxU1dha2lXd3ZIbTFJTkFvQ1FBPQotLS0tLUVORCBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCg==
        key: ""
    certSANs: []
    kubelet:
        image: ghcr.io/siderolabs/kubelet:v1.31.1
        defaultRuntimeSeccompProfileEnabled: true
        disableManifestsDirectory: true
    network: {}
    install:
        disk: /dev/sda
        image: ghcr.io/siderolabs/installer:v1.9.0-alpha.0
        wipe: false
    features:
        rbac: true
        stableHostname: true
        apidCheckExtKeyUsage: true
        diskQuotaSupport: true
        kubePrism:
            enabled: true
            port: 7445
        hostDNS:
            enabled: true
            forwardKubeDNSToHost: true
cluster:
    id: bbNeeJ5ih8rcxrnVBIJeARbRq--ZVoSv0X3GYqrvuQY=
    secret: b8neVYsNEDaq/DlMoJiB3291LPOrmxra2SFibLglUvg=
    controlPlane:
        endpoint: https://10.0.1.101:6443
    clusterName: homelab
    network:
        dnsDomain: cluster.local
        podSubnets:
            - 10.244.0.0/16
        serviceSubnets:
            - 10.96.0.0/12
    token: n8zjw3.7vmywofpuzl1ii4r
    ca:
        crt: 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
        key: ""
    discovery:
        enabled: true
        registries:
            kubernetes:
                disabled: true
            service: {}

